# jQuery delay data-goto till fadeIn is complete

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a button which triggers going to the next slide/section of the site. However before it slide in the next panel I would like the button to display a tick to show the user that is what they selected, then load in the next slide.

Here is my HTML:

```
<button class="pt-trigger" data-animation="1" data-goto="-1">Go to next page</button>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$('.pt-trigger').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.tick').fadeIn('slow');
        $pageTrigger = $(this);
        Animate($pageTrigger);
    });
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.tick {
position: absolute;
right: 5px;
top: -2px;
font-size:19px;
display:none;}

.pt-trigger {
background:none;
border: none;
font-size: 25px;
margin: 10px 0 10px;
padding: 15px 0px;
line-height: 40px;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
font-weight:normal;
border:1px solid #fff;
color:#fff;
width:262px;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
float:left;}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peh5u/) as well.

---

Update:
How do i create a delay before the slide animation?

```
 $('.pt-trigger').click(function() {
         $(this).find('.tick').fadeIn(900, function() {
            $pageTrigger = $('.pt-trigger').delay(3000);
            Animate($pageTrigger);
        });   
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**.fadeIn()**](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) accepts a callback as the 2nd parameter. Pass in an anonymous function, which will be executed once the animation has completed.

Be careful not to run into context issues.

```
$('.pt-trigger').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.tick').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        //do stuff after the animation is complete
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, thats what im looking for. Is there a way to do it so that it looks to see if the button has a div.tick within it then if the button doesn't have div.tick in it, it still does the animation.

Comment: To check for the existence of an element, you can do if ($('.myClass').length) {...}

Comment: Great thank you. Im trying to currently make a delay happen after The fade in has occured. So the tick fades in, theres a delay and then the next section slides in. I have updated my code

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting to do is animate your page within the `callback` function of your `tick` animation.

```
$('.pt-trigger').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('.tick').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        // I am a callback function
        // that runs after .tick loads
        // do animation now, etc.
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, thats what im looking for. However im now looking to see if there is a way to do it so that it looks to see if the button has a div.tick within it then if the button doesn't have div.tick in it, it still does the animation.ixed it. Thank you for your help

Comment: Then you would do: if ( $(".pt-trigger").has(".tick") ) { // fade in and do animation} else { // do animation }